# Regex pattern for my below mentioned requirement

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting very confused in writing the regex pattern for my requirement.
I want that a text field should not accept any special character except underscore and hyphen. Also, it shouldn't accept underscore, hyphen, and space if entered alone in the text field.

I tried following pattern->

```
/[ !@#$%^&*()+\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/;
```

but this is also allowing underscore and hyphen, as well as space if entered alone.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than matching what you do not want, you should match what you actually want.
 Since you never specified if you string could have letter, number and spaces in it, i just assumed it was a single word, so I matched uppercase and lowercase letters only, with underscore and hyphen.

```
^(([A-Za-z])+([\-|_ ])?)+$
```

I have created a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/krzjeD/3) if you wish to try more cases.

Comment: The above regex is matching my requirement, except one scenario. Let me mention that there can be any number of words that can be entered in text field. It should not accept any special character in b/w the words, or beginning/end except underscore and hyphen. Here the exception is that it should not accept underscore, hyphen as well as empty space if entered alone in the text field.

Comment: It should accept space, underscore and hyphen if given in b/w the words.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your string not to contain special characters except underscore and hyphen. But there is an exception for that if they contain space with the hyphen and underscore, then you can handle that exception separately. This will make your code easier to understand and easily adaptable for further exceptions.

```js
function validateString(str){

  let reg = /[^!@#$%^&*()+\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g;
  let match = str.match(reg);
  console.log(match);
 if(match && (match.includes(" ") || match.includes("_") || match.includes("-")) && (!match.join(",").match(/[a-zA-Z]/))){
    // regex contains invalid characters 
    console.log(str + ": Invalid input");
  }
  else if(match){
    console.log(str + ": Valid string");
  }

}

let str = "-_  ";

let str1 = "Mathus-Mark";
let str2 = "Mathus Mark";
let str3 = "Mathus_Mark";
let str4 = " ";
let str5 = "-";
let str6 = "_";


validateString(str);
validateString(str1);
validateString(str2);
validateString(str3);
validateString(str4);
validateString(str5);
validateString(str6);
```

Comment: Thanks for you time..The solution is not working if in a text field, we will enter underscore/hyphen/empty space alone...It is allowing them, but it shouldn't. Suppose we have str = "_", str1 = "-", str2 = " ", it should throw error in this case also. These three things should be allowed only when these will be entered with string, not alone.

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought that all three together won't be allowed. I have updated my answer.